# Use of PyTorch permute in RCNN

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, lstm

I am looking at an implementation of RCNN for text classification using PyTorch. [Full Code](https://github.com/AnubhavGupta3377/Text-Classification-Models-Pytorch/blob/master/Model_RCNN/model.py). There are two points where the dimensions of tensors are permuted using the `permute` function. The first is after the LSTM layer and before tanh. The second is after a linear layer and before a max pooling layer.

Could you please explain why the permutation is necessary or useful?

**Relevant Code**

```
    def forward(self, x):
        # x.shape = (seq_len, batch_size)
        embedded_sent = self.embeddings(x)
        # embedded_sent.shape = (seq_len, batch_size, embed_size)

        lstm_out, (h_n,c_n) = self.lstm(embedded_sent)
        # lstm_out.shape = (seq_len, batch_size, 2 * hidden_size)
        
        input_features = torch.cat([lstm_out,embedded_sent], 2).permute(1,0,2)
        # final_features.shape = (batch_size, seq_len, embed_size + 2*hidden_size)
        
        linear_output = self.tanh(
            self.W(input_features)
        )
        # linear_output.shape = (batch_size, seq_len, hidden_size_linear)
        
        linear_output = linear_output.permute(0,2,1) # Reshaping fot max_pool
        
        max_out_features = F.max_pool1d(linear_output, linear_output.shape[2]).squeeze(2)
        # max_out_features.shape = (batch_size, hidden_size_linear)
        
        max_out_features = self.dropout(max_out_features)
        final_out = self.fc(max_out_features)
        return self.softmax(final_out)
```

**Similar Code in other Repositories**

Similar implementations of RCNN use `permute` or `transpose`. Here are examples:

- https://github.com/prakashpandey9/Text-Classification-Pytorch/blob/master/models/RCNN.py
- https://github.com/jungwhank/rcnn-text-classification-pytorch/blob/master/model.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What `permute` function does is **rearranges the original tensor according to the desired ordering**, note `permute` is different from `reshape` function, because when apply `permute`, the elements in tensor follow the index you provide where in `reshape` it's not.

Example code:

```
import torch 
var = torch.randn(2, 4)
pe_var = var.permute(1, 0)
re_var = torch.reshape(var, (4, 2))
print("Original size:\n{}\nOriginal var:\n{}\n".format(var.size(), var) + 
      "Permute size:\n{}\nPermute var:\n{}\n".format(pe_var.size(), pe_var) + 
      "Reshape size:\n{}\nReshape var:\n{}\n".format(re_var.size(), re_var))
```

Outputs:

```
Original size:
torch.Size([2, 4])
Original var:
tensor([[ 0.8250, -0.1984,  0.5567, -0.7123],
        [-1.0503,  0.0470, -1.9473,  0.9925]])
Permute size:
torch.Size([4, 2])
Permute var:
tensor([[ 0.8250, -1.0503],
        [-0.1984,  0.0470],
        [ 0.5567, -1.9473],
        [-0.7123,  0.9925]])
Reshape size:
torch.Size([4, 2])
Reshape var:
tensor([[ 0.8250, -0.1984],
        [ 0.5567, -0.7123],
        [-1.0503,  0.0470],
        [-1.9473,  0.9925]])
```

With the role of `permute` in mind we could see what first `permute` does is reordering the concatenate tensor for it to fit the inputs format of `self.W`, i.e with batch as first dimension; and the second `permute` does similar thing because we want to max pool the `linear_output` along the sequence and `F.max_pool1d` will pool along the last dimension.

Comment: Good description of permute vs. reshape.

Answer (score 2):

I am adding this answer to provide additional PyTorch-specific details.

It is necessary to use `permute` between `nn.LSTM` and `nn.Linear` because the output shape of LSTM does not correspond to the expected input shape of Linear.

`nn.LSTM` outputs `output, (h_n, c_n)`. Tensor `output` has shape `seq_len, batch, num_directions * hidden_size` [nn.LSTM](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LSTM.html). `nn.Linear` expects an input tensor with shape `N,∗,H`, where `N` is batch size and `H` is number of input features. [nn.Linear](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Linear.html).

It is necessary to use `permute` between `nn.Linear` and `nn.MaxPool1d` because the output of `nn.Linear` is N, L, C, where N is batch size, C is the number of features, and and L is sequence length. `nn.MaxPool1d` expects an input tensor of shape N, C, L. [nn.MaxPool1d](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.MaxPool1d.html)

I reviewed seven implementations of RCNN for text classification with PyTorch on GitHub and gitee and found that `permute` and `transpose` are the normal ways to convert the output of one layer to the input of a subsequent layer.